# How may I reuse an asterisk-globbed path in zsh?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

My question and the title may not be very well-formed, and I apologise in advance for that.

Suppose I would like to execute a command (to be specific, [`xsdcxx`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsdcxx)) as such in `zsh`:

```bsh
$ xsdcxx cxx-tree schemas/core/**/*.xsd --output-dir /absolute/path/to/globbed/path
```

so that the directory structure of the generated files are in the same directory as the input `.xsd` schemas. How do I do this? In PowerShell, this is quite straightforward (assuming `xsdcxx` is already in the `PATH`):

```
> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include '*.xsd' | Foreach { xsdcxx cxx-tree --output-dir $_.Directory.Fullname $_.Fullname }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `zsh`, that would be just:

```
for f (schemas/core/**/*.xsd) xsdcxx cxx-tree --output-dir $f:h $f
```

Where `$f:h` is the head (dirname) of `$f` like in csh or vim.

Change `$f` to `$f:P` and `$f:h` to `$f:h:P` to get the *realpath*¹ of the file and file head respectively.

Here, you may want to change `schemas/core/**/*.xsd` to `schemas/core/**/*.xsd(N)` (where `N` enables `nullglob` for that one glob expansion) to avoid the error if there's no match. Or `(N.)` to restrict to regular files only (excluding all other types of files like sockets, fifos, directories, symlinks etc), or `(N-.)` to also include symlinks to regular files.

---

<sup>¹, that is the canonical path to the corresponding file: absolute and symlink-free, like with the `realpath()` standard function. See also the `:a` and `:A` modifiers described at `info zsh modifiers` as possible alternatives.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the clear, detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want something like:

```
for i in schemas/core/**/*.xsd; do xsdcxx cxx-tree "$i" --output-dir "${i%/*}"; done
```

Where `${i%/*}` removes the shortest trailing substring that starts with `/` (effectively resulting in the path to the parent directory).

Comment: Beware that if the glob is changed to `**/*.xsd`, the `$i` could be set to `foobar.xsd`, and then `${i%/*}` would expand to `foobar.xsd` (while `$i:h` would expand to the more correct `.`).

Comment: Would changing the `${i%/*}` to `$(dirname "$i")` be an option?

Comment: @AdminBee, rather `"$(dirname -- "$i")"`, but then you've got the usual issue with `i=$'weird\ndir\n\n\n/file.xsd'`. Again `$i:h` in zsh (which the OP is using and wanting an answer for) has none of those problems.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True, and since the OP specifically mentioned `zsh` your answer is exactly right. Only it would have been nice to support murus attempt in providing a portable solution (albeit it would depend on an external tool).

Comment: @AdminBee, `**/` is already a zsh-ism.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas D'oh you are right; I sometimes forget that even in bash you need `globstar` for that (and others may not have it at all)

Comment: @AdminBee, yes, bash was actually one of the last ones to add it and implementation is still quite broken there. See also [The result of ls \* , ls \*\* and ls \*\*\*](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/62665). In any case the behaviour of `**/` where supported varies significantly between shell implementations. See also https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/146